# WordPress - Cannot get add_rewrite_rule() to work

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a rewrite rule going on a page in my WordPress website.

I have a page called **latest**, with a custom template and it has an ID of **10**.

At the moment, I am making several dynamic requests based on the query string like so:

> example.com/latest/?type=instagram

What I would like instead is:

> example.com/latest/instagram/

Here's what I've tried so far.

**functions.php**

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=10&type=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I was following the guide found here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

For the life of me, I cannot get this to work. It simply forwards to my 404 page or tries to find a post that has a title *sort of* matching the type parameter and redirects me.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong? I have refreshed the permalinks too.

Comment: For what you are trying to do, you actually want [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Comment: @cale_b Thanks - any examples using this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I have an extra path in the rewrite rule.

Instead of: `'^latest/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?'` it should have been: `'^latest/([^/]*)/?'`

My new working function in `functions.php` is as follows:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=10&type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 1);
```

Hope this helps someone in future!